# the adverb between verb and preposition

Tags: adverbs

A example:

> I care more about others

and

> I care about others more

Is there any difference between both sentences?

- for first sentence:

  Does `more` modifies verb `care` or prep `about` ?
- for second sentence:

  what word does `more` modify?
- for preposition `about`:

  Can I use `more` to modify `about`?

Last question: is there any general rule ?

Comment: In both cases "more" modifies the verb phrase "care about others".

Comment: I can't easily see any potential for a semantic distinction with the example as given. But I'm in no doubt that *Having read your letter, I **think more** of you* would nearly always be interpreted as meaning *I think **more highly** of you* (you have gone up in my estimation). On the other hand, *...I **think** of you **more*** would be interpreted as meaning *I think of you **more often*** (I'm preoccupied with thinking about you). In short, just because ***more*** modifies ***think*** in both cases doesn't mean they're semantically equivalent.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I think if I interpret it as 'I think **more of you**', it seems right too.

Comment: *to care **about*** usually refers to either ***being concerned** [about someone's welfare]* OR ***being annoyed** [by something]*. But you haven't provided enough context to say which of those (or something totally different) applies. Note that trhere's also *to care **for***, which usually means either ***to look after*** someone, or ***to feel great affection*** for them. But the distinction I just flagged up above doesn't seem so relevant to *I care more for him / I care for him more*, where (to me, at least) both versions are equally likely to carry either of those different senses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the first sentence:

   Does *more* modify the verb **care** or the preposition **about**?

   ***More* modifies the verb ***care***.**
2. For the second sentence:

   What word does *more* modify?

   **It also modifies the verb ***care***.**
3. The preposition **about**:

   Can I use more to modify **about**?

   **No.**
4. Last question: is there any general rule?

   Yes.  In this case, you want to put this adverb as close to the word it modifies as possible.

Consider these:

> I care more about winning.
>
> I care about winning more.

Some adverbs must be near the word or phrase they modify.

[image]

Comment: If `only` could modifies `after`, why can't I think `more` modifies `about`?

Comment: @yixuan  Good! The reason is simple: "care about" is idiomatic.